# Conditional statements in Field Calculator QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, conditional

Is it possible to modify the following syntax somehow that it would be applicable in Field Calculator in QGIS? The input layer is point layer and I would like to do following calculations which I can't do in Excel due to large amount of data.

```
if(  "VALUE1" < 0.01, 2,
  if( AND( "VALUE1" >= 0.01, "VALUE1" < 0.1 ), 3,
    if( OR( "VALUE1" >= 0.1, "VALUE2"  >= 2 ),  4, 0 )
  )
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please describe more detailled what you are trying to achieve. Currently your chaining of `if`, `and` and `or` is absolutely wrong.

Comment: ... or right ... but **not** in QGIS syntax at least ...

Comment: @Erik Its not QGIS syntax. I would like to transform this Excel syntax to QGIS syntax for field calculator if possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just offset the logical operators and petr's syntax is right (imho)

```
if("VALUE1"<0.01,2,if("VALUE1">=0.01 AND "VALUE1"<0.1,3,if("VALUE1" >=0.1 OR "VALUE2">=2,4,0)))
```

Comment: Thank you, in the end my expression turned out to be close to correct one.

Comment: Yep you're right ... where does your syntax come from ?

Comment: What do you mean? Its from Ecxel and has been edited by someone here on this thread to this form. My original idea was to do it in Excel, however I have over 1.200.000 points with more columns and Ecel could not handle the data. After the calculalation was done I used rasterize tool to create a raster with values 2,3, and 4.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `CASE WHEN` statement. 
I will give you an example, adapt it.

```
CASE WHEN  "VALUE1" < 0.01 THEN 2
WHEN "VALUE1" >= 0.01 AND "VALUE1" < 0.1 THEN 3 
ELSE 4
END
```

I applied this formula to the `VALUE2` field, here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your method worked.